# Dispaly records from database in magento

Tags: mysql, magento

I am using this code in my Grid.php to display records from a single tabel 'paypal_payment_transaction':

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
 $db = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');

$query = "SELECT transaction_id,txn_id,additional_information,created_at,user_id,reference_txn
FROM `paypal_payment_transaction`
LIMIT 0 , 30";

$result = $db->query($query);

// Get count of affected rows
$affected_rows = $result->rowCount();
$orders = $result->fetchAll($sql);
foreach($orders as $order)
{
echo "<pre>"; print_r($order);
}

}
```

I need this query in magento way:
may be like this

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
    {

      $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')
           SOME QUERY TO SELECT RECORD FROM TABEL 'paypal_payment_transaction'
        ;

        $this->setCollection($collection);
        parent::_prepareCollection();
        return $this;
    }
```

So that I can display it in grid accordingly i.e. in :

```
protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        -------------------

 ------------------

}
```

Comment: do u want these records in sales/order grid?

Comment: no. I had made a seprate custom module for this page in admin. There I want this to display

Comment: what is the name of the model for the table `paypal_payment_transaction` in your `config.xml`.?

Comment: I dont Know how to find out this. will you please suggest

Comment: in your config.xml what is written between `<models>` and `</models>` ?

Comment: I had searched under Mage>Payment>etc>config.xml and found this code:<models>
            <payment>
                <class>Mage_Payment_Model</class>
            </payment>
        </models>

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
      $collection = Mage::getModel('paypal/payment_transaction')->getCollection();
      $this->setCollection($collection);
      parent::_prepareCollection();
      return $this;
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it gives : There has been an error processing your request

Comment: Is it possible to get records in grid using this code: $db = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write'); that I had mentioned in my question. As this code giving me output But I dont know how to use it to display records in grid in admin

Comment: And also is it possible to get these records in sales/order grid?

Comment: There has been an error processing your request

Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

Error log record number: 1110424306

Comment: go to var/report and open the report no 1110424306 and then see the error

Comment: and in var/report it gives error: a:5:{i:0;s:98:"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'main_table.transaction_id' in 'field list'";i:1;s:6016:"#0 /var/www/html/freshgemstone/gemstone/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)

Comment: i havent taken transaction_id anywhere. please check if the column exists in the table or not

Comment: var/report 1110424306: a:5:{i:0;s:87:"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'increment_id' in 'order clause'";i:1;s:6016:"#0 /var/www/html/freshgemstone/gemstone/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)

Comment: Its done actually Increment_id is an extra field Iam using. Its working now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can try the following code

```html
protected function _prepareCollection()
{

      $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('payment/transaction')
          $Collection->addFieldToSelect('transaction_id');
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        parent::_prepareCollection();
        return $this;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: It give me blank screen